# Password required after restart: Incorrect password problem

Tags: realme

I have the same exact problem as this user [My android phone won't accept correct PIN/password after I tried to change my screen lock password](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248106/my-android-phone-wont-accept-correct-pin-password-after-i-tried-to-change-my-sc)

My phone was turned off because the battery died. When it turns on after i charged it, it requires password after restart.

I entered the correct password (because i have done this many times before) but this time it says incorrect password.

Even in recovery mode, i tried the online update option but it requires the lockscreen password, which, it too, says incorrect despite entering the correct one.

Im using realme x7 pro

Comment: If it died in the middle of changing it, then try fragments of your password

Comment: How can i do that?